# Preload key requests LightHouse

Tags: font-awesome, performance-testing, google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I am using `font-awesome` for icons in `angular` app. I checked my web result in `pagespeed`. I getting an issue with fonts.

Here is `pagespeed` result.

[image]

its said use `<link rel=preload>` but the problem is that `..fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0` is available in `FontAwesome`'s css file, So how can i add preload for this? or there is any solution for fix it?

Here is my index.html where i included `font-awesome` cdn.

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin />
```

I think Here is the problem in `css`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 ways to accomplish this.

1. Use it in local. You know the rest.
2. Tell browser that "I am going to call these files shortly, be prepared."

Use `preconnect`. (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization?hl=en#preconnect)

Make sure you use `as="font"`.

```
<link rel="preconnect" as="font"
href="https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0" type="font/eot"
crossorigin />
```

3. Tell browser that "I want you to fetch them asap."

   `<link rel="preload" as="font"
   href="https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0"
   type="font/eot" crossorigin="anonymous">`

For point 2 and 3, replicate the same for woff and woff2. Declare correct mime types in type.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using WordPress platform and facing this issue then check out this article on to [fix preload key request](http://freelancersiddheshlad.com/fix-preload-key-requests-with-fonts-in-wordpress/)
Simply you can use a WordPress plugin to add preload key to Fonts known as “Asset CleanUp“
Install plugin go to `setting->Local Fonts-> Add URL` there and it will be fixed.
For more info visit below Ref URL
http://freelancersiddheshlad.com/fix-preload-key-requests-with-fonts-in-wordpress/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ensure your answer addresses the question that was asked so that is is relevant and therefore helpful .This question states that it is for the `angular` app. There is no reference to Wordpress.